# How many process are created in this program?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, posix

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
    int i = 3;
    int pid;
    while(i > 0) {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid > 0) {
            exit(0);
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

How many process are created on that program??? I am still confused with the fork() system calls, can anybody help me to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does `fork()` do?

`fork()` is an interesting call. You can think of it as cloning the state of your program into two exact copies -- the only difference between them will be the return value of `fork()`. The process that did the `fork()` receives the process id (pid) of the new process, while the new process receives `0`.

With that in mind:

#### How many processes are created?

Each time you fork, you create a new process and exit the parent. You do this three times, therefore -- three processes are created by forking. This doesn't include the one that you started by starting the process, of course. :)

Comment: Thank you I now fully understand why, how and when the processes are created using fork() system calls :)

Comment: and i have one more question, if i move the [i--] statement to the parent process from the child process, will the processes equal to zero? or the program execute infinite loop?

Comment: Nope, the answer will remain the same: three processes created, as long as you keep the answer the same. Now here's a question: comment out the `exit(0)` -- how many processes are created then?

Comment: if i comment out the exit(0) statement it will executing the parent process too i think, so the total process become 8?

Comment: If you comment out the `exit(0)`, it continues forking indefinitely (try it... carefully!) Now: what happens if you replace that loop with `for(i=3;i>0;i--) fork();`?

Comment: it will forking three times and has 8 processes

Comment: Yep! I think you fully get it -- happy programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. during start of you program, system creates 1 process (+1)
2. i=3, program creates new process (+1), parent exits, child continue
3. i=2, program creates new process (+1), parent exits, child continue
4. i=1, program creates new process (+1), parent exits, child continue
5. i=0, program exit

so, totally - 4 processes, 3 created by program, 1 by system

Comment: Thank you I now fully understand why, how and when the processes are created using fork() system calls :)